# Changing the viewcontroller's default view to new instance of uiview

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I want to change the default view of UIViewController with a new custom UIView intance but i got diffrent behavior for ios and tvos.

when i am adding new view to replace viewcontroller's view like this :

```
let viewcontroller: UIViewController!
let rootview:UIView!

viewcontroller = UIViewController ()

rootview = UIView (frame:viewcontroller.view.bounds)

viewcontroller.view = rootview

// Adding a button
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for:.allEvents)

viewcontroller.view.addSubview(button)
```

For ios(iPhone/ipad) , i am able to get button click event .
But in case of tvOS , i am not getting button click event.

But in case of tvOS if use the default view of viewcontroller like this , i am getting button click events and things works fine:

```
let viewcontroller: UIViewController!

viewcontroller = UIViewController ()

// Adding a button
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for:.allEvents)

viewcontroller.view.addSubview(button)
```

Is this some bug for tvOS or for tvOS this suppose to happen this way ?

Answer (score 0):

Directly setting a view controller's view is unsupported (except within the view controller's `loadView` method), so what you were doing was always wrong and you should have no expectations of its working on any platform.

The correct way to accomplish what you're attempting is to *cover* the existing view with another view (as its subview), which can either be a simple stand-alone view or can be the view of a *different* view controller which you configure as a child view controller of this one.